# on cascade delete in android Sqlite 3.7.11 not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 3 table in helper

1)Login_Table  table for user information Storing 
2)Service_Table for Storing services having one column  references to Login_Table table 
3)SubService_Table for Storing sub services having one column references to service_table and another Login_Table table

i want to delete row from particular service table then automatic delete record from the subservice row which reference to service table id table but when i delete particular row from service table it force to be close

`db.execSQL( " CREATE TABLE "+ LoginTable +" ( " +login_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + NAME + " TEXT, " + USERNAME + " TEXT, " +PASSWORD + " TEXT," + GENDER + " TEXT, " + CONTACT + " TEXT, " + SQUE + " TEXT, " + ANSWER + " TEXT, " + EmailId + " TEXT, " + UType+" TEXT)");`

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Services+"("+Ser_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  "+Ser_Name+" TEXT, "+Ser_UID+" Integer not null, FOREIGN KEY ("+Ser_UID+") REFERENCES "+LoginTable+" ("+login_ID+"));");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Sub_Services+"("+Sub_Ser_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  "+Sub_Ser_Name+" TEXT, "+Ref_Ser_ID+" Integer not null, "+Sub_Ser_UID+" Integer not null, FOREIGN KEY ("+Ref_Ser_ID+") REFERENCES "+Services+" ("+Ser_ID+") ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY ("+Sub_Ser_UID+") REFERENCES "+LoginTable+" ("+login_ID+")) ;");

i also used enable foreign key by following code

```
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }
```

How cascade delete exactly use in android SQLite?? i used android 4.2 and version of sqlite 3.7.11...

Comment: Forced close? Show the logcat with the exception information.

Comment: it shows exception "unfortunately stopped" and when i checked logcat i found where i put delete query for deleting selected row of service table(parent of sub_service)

Comment: Error message from logcat: at com.example.nilbook.Ofeedservices.onClick(Ofeedservices.java:82)

Comment: The entire stack trace!